# Tfp.sts unexpected wights prior behavior

Tags: time-series, probability, causality, tensorflow

I am trying to build a time series structural model and get the coefficients of the external factor. 
 here is the structure of the model

```
    observed_time_series=ts, 
    name='LLT'
)

day_of_week = tfp.sts.Seasonal(
    num_seasons=7, 
    num_steps_per_season=1,
    observed_time_series=ts, 
    name='day_of_week',
)

month_of_year = tfp.sts.Seasonal(
    num_seasons=12, 
    num_steps_per_season=30,
    observed_time_series=ts, 
    name='month_of_year',
)


yearweek = tfp.sts.Seasonal(
    num_seasons=52, 
    num_steps_per_season=7,
    observed_time_series=ts, 
    name='yearweek',
)
x_var = tfp.sts.LinearRegression(
    design_matrix=design_matrix_fb,
    weights_prior=tfd.Exponential(rate=2),
    name='external_factor')

model_components_base = [
    local_linear_trend, 
    day_of_week,
    month_of_year,
    x_var
]

model_base = tfp.sts.Sum(
    components=model_components_base, 
    observed_time_series=ts
)
```

then I  am sampling and plotting the prior distribution using this function

```
variational_posteriors = tfp.sts.build_factored_surrogate_posterior(
  model=direct_model_base, 
  seed=42
)
q_prior_samples = variational_posteriors.sample(200) 
num_parameters = len(direct_model_base.parameters)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(num_parameters, 1, figsize=(12, 21))

for i, param in enumerate(direct_model_base.parameters):

    param_mean = np.mean(q_prior_samples[param.name], axis=0)
    param_median = np.median(q_prior_samples[param.name], axis=0)
    param_std = np.std(q_prior_samples[param.name], axis=0)

    sns.distplot(a=q_prior_samples[param.name], rug=True, ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].set(title=param.name)
    ax[i].axvline(x= param_median, linestyle='--', label='median')
    ax[i].axvline(x= param_mean, linestyle='--', label='mean')
    ax[i].axvline(x= param_mean + param_std, linestyle='--', label=r'$\mu \pm 2\sigma$')
    ax[i].axvline(x= param_mean - param_std, linestyle='--')
    ax[i].legend()

plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
plt.suptitle('PRIOR DISTRIBUTIONS', y=0.99);
```

Even tho the weight_prior of the external factor is setted to an exponential distribution i get this plot for the external factor's weight normal dist with negative values ! 
 Am I missing something or understanding something wrongly here

[Weights prior distribution result](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24575436/81730149-5f655f00-948d-11ea-8aeb-6cb8c980268a.png)

Comment: have you found answer to this question?